# JAVA: Find polygons in a set of edges

Tags: java, graph, nodes, polygon

I'm creating a Java program where now I have to manage the white edges and get all the possible polygons from the figure.

For example, given [this drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1sf8.png), I would like to get all of [these polygons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxPIv.png).

Having stored all the white edges with both points,
How could I do this?

Thank you in advice

Comment: can you provide a sample set of points , its very hard to create data for what you have tried and provide a solution.

Comment: This could be computer vision or simple math - but if you have the white points then you need to fit straight lines to them - then from the straight lines you get the polygons

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but perhaps Graph Theory might be of help here.  I only really looks at a couple of topics, but given a polygon in your dataset could be what Graph Theory considers a Cycle, I would be surprised if there are not methods for finding Cycles in a set of vertices.

[Graph Theory](https://youtu.be/eIb1cz06UwI) is a good set of youtube videos covering the basics